# iOS: UIImageView after UILabel with multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

I've got a multiline UILabel that have sometimes 1 line or max 3 lines of text. Under the UILabel is a UIImageView.
The UIImageView should always have the same exact padding between UILabel and UIImageView, no matter if there are 1 or 3 lines in UILabel.

I dont use Autolayout in my View, because I couldn't get it working, that an UILabel get stretched over the full width of the UIView.

Does anybody can explain me, how to positioning the UIImageView under the UILabel correctly with the same padding? Thanks!

Comment: *I dont use Autolayout in my View, because I couldn't get it working* ... learn using Auto Layout !

Comment: there is another way also..1st add text in the label then add attributedtext with image in label it will give you same padding all time

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference with the top position of your UILabel for positioning the UIImageView under your label always with the same padding. Before that you need to call *sizeToFit* method in the new label that has been created.

```
NSString *text = @"Some text here...";

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[myLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[myLabel setText:text];
[myLabel sizeToFit];

CGFloat posY = myLabel.frame.origin.y + myLabel.frame.size.height;

UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, posY, 300, 300)];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). This is the best way to achieve your goals and position your views.
2. Anyother way is to use `boundingRectWithSize` from [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:). With this method you can calculate the size of the text inside your UILabel and change the frame of the UIImage on runtime.